Size of generator to run a 14K btu portable A/C unit
I'm looking to run a 15k btu wall A/C unit on a generator. I've been told that the NEC specifies an 8x load rating for the generator to start an A/C unit.
The specific unit I'm looking at is actually a 14K btu, non-inverter, and a 15k btu unit supposedly takes 15 Amps peak. At 120v that's roughly 1.4kw (considering a power factor of 0.8)
So the conclusion is that any generator with more than 1.4kw will run it comfortably.
So an Engineer popped in and said that's what it takes to run it. To start the A/C unit, he said the NEC says it takes a generator of 8x, or a 14kw generator.
That's a big generator.
Is that accurate? I asked him for the NEC reference and he couldn't find it, but said it absolutely specifies that to start motors of that size. In fact, he said:

Many solid state generators “Inverters” Fail on this point, because they will instantly close down , if their limits are exceeded. . . .

I've been using a Champion dual fuel 3100 inverter generator - 2800 on propane - for about 5 years to start and run this A/C unit. That's only 2x the rated capacity.
Is my generator in danger of burning up and 'instantly closing down'?

A portable generator does not fall under NEC.

It might trip a breaker on the generator, but after five years with no problem, I doubt it is being hurt.  I had a borrowed little honda gen, maybe a 1000 or 1500 amps.  It ran a well pump with no problem with a long small gauge extension.  After got a bigger 5000 amp gen, It would only run the well pump with a short 10 gauge extension without tripping breakers.

BTUs get confusing. BTU and kWh are in one way equivalent - one 1 kWh of electricity turned directly into heat (e.g., toaster) is 3,412 BTU. But when you are talking about BTU of cooling, the efficiency matters. Ignore all rules of thumb. Look at your air conditioner. It should have information on it regarding the amount of power (or current) it requires. That is the determining factor, possibly with a multiplier of some sort for startup. The one difference with a generator is that with utility power if you go over (but not too much over) for a short time, your breaker will (by design)

not trip. If you go over the capacity of a generator it will shut down. But many generators have a "peak" capacity beyond the regular running capacity to handle exactly this issue reasonably well. And since you have used this AC with this generator for a while without a problem, you're OK.

Not what you're looking at, but: Inverter drive variable speed AC/heat-pump units don't have a huge starting surge, because they start at low speed - making for a far "softer" start than any "soft-start kit" on a fixed-speed compressor going from 0 to maximum speed as fast as it can.
Once running, they will ramp up as the load calls for more cooling, and slow down again as it calls for less.

Impossible to say. There is no decoder ring between BTU/hr and watts, these are not units which convert to each other.  Like if I said "pay me fuel for 500 miles" that's not enough information since all cars have different MPGs.  There once was, a long time ago, when all A/C units where same cheap basic units with terrible SEER. (BTUs/watt, coarsely).

If it ain't broke, don't fix it.
The reason for that vast factor of eight times is because motors, particularly compressor motors, draw a high initial startup current. Some air conditioners have a soft start feature to reduce that initial load.
What would happen if the AC drew too much current for the generator on startup? The generator might stall, or the circuit breaker would trip. It's unlikely there would be any damage, and the issue would occur only when the AC cycles on.
Since you experience no problems, then, most likely, the generator has sufficient inertia and the circuit breaker is "slow blow" (allowing a moderate overload for a second or two), giving that particular AC enough time to start. It is doing no harm. However, that is not to say if you replaced the AC that a new one would work without tripping the breaker. When buying another AC, be sure it has soft start.

Thanks. A commenter on Quora double down twice and insisted that I needed an 8x unit - because the NEC required it - despite real world experience, so I was also looking to see what the NEC said. Apparently it doesn't cover portable generators so the point is moot.

Also, the OLD A/C unit didn't specifically mention inverter or soft start. It's getting old now - 8yrs old and a lot of trips to "That thing in the desert" so I may just replace it soon anyway; in which case I'll make sure it's an "Inverter A/C" or soft start. No trailer mounted generators!

See if you can buy it in a place that allows returns, and test the AC on your generator as soon as you buy it. Again, if it starts and runs, and restarts (restarting an AC after it has run a while is more difficult), there should be no problem.

Well, it's been in use for nearly 7 years, so I'd say it's working fine. It was more looking at what NEC required, and it doesn't.
